# How to suppress GCC compiler warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z

Tags: gcc, g++, c++17, compiler-warnings

I am using an inline global variable which works well for the purpose of it.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void Func() {
    }
}

inline MyClass myClass;  // global inline variable
```

Above works well for my purpose but I get a warning when my code compiles on gcc with compiler below C++17. Following is the warning

> warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or
>   -std=gnu++1z

**Question:**
How can I suppress the warning on gcc?

I tried to suppress the warning by using a `#pragma` like below

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wc++17-extensions"
inline MyClass myClass;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Above `#pragma` technique works on clang, but looks like GCC to not understand the `#pragma`? I just want to brute force suppress the warning on GCC. How can I do that?

Looks like gcc warning options list does not even mention about this?
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

I am using **gcc (GCC) 7.3.0**

Comment: Why not just do what the warning says and use the `-std=c++1z` flag?

Comment: I tried that. It then complains `warning: ‘-std=c++1z’ is not an option that controls warnings [-Wpragmas]`

Comment: I meant compile it with `-std=c++1z` as a command line option for the `gcc` command? Maybe add it to `CPPFLAGS` if your build system supports that.

Comment: Does not look like my build system supports that. I am a bit unsure if I can change the build system for such a small thing. I am using Cmake by the way. **But,** My question was more towards how to brute force silence the warning by usage of some flag in the cpp source file (given that my build system supports C++11)

Comment: Ok. Is there a way I can silence the warning from my `CMakeLists.txt`? That is second preferred option for me but if there is no way at all to silence this warning from source code then I will have resort to doing something in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg: You are using a C++17 feature when you have not told the compiler to compile your code as C++17. The options for "silencing" the warning are to either compile your code as C++17 or remove the C++17 feature from your non-C++17 code.

Comment: Ok. I thought that since the compiler has figured out that inline variables are a C++17 feature and warning about it, it might also have a way to silence the warning. Or there might be some magic #pragma to silence whatever warning it was there. But looks like not. Thanks for responses.

Comment: If you don't use C++17 you'll get different semantics, e.g. duplicate symbols, or alternatively (if you declare the variable static instead) several objects instead of one. So the question is: What *is* the purpose?

Comment: I cannot declare it as static. Singleton is a bit of anti pattern. So, I had resorted to declaring it inline. But then to have it inline without a warning, I need C++17 :-(

Comment: I cannot upgrade to C++17 but I wanted to have something without a warning. Looks like I have to make `MyClass` as a singleton :-( . Thats the only when since there seems no way silence the warning.

Comment: If a singleton is an antipattern then you shouldn't use an inline variable either; it's just a different syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand why you cannot suppress this warning, look at what happens if the code is compiled with a compiler that does not support inline variables. ([Inline variable support started with gcc 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17).) Older versions of gcc process your code and spit out `error: 'myClass' declared as an 'inline' variable`. Not a warning, but an unsuppressible **error**. Hard stop; object code not produced.

Newer versions of gcc are able to be more understanding and helpful, but at the same time they have an obligation to maintain some degree of compatibility with older compilers. These newer compilers can recognize this C++17 feature, and it's been determined that ignoring "`inline`" downgrades the error to a warning (compilation does not necessarily need to stop). Furthermore, the message was given information about how to resolve this situation (assuming the code is correct). At the same time, this warning is still essentially the error produced by older versions of gcc, just given a makeover to make it more user-friendly. It cannot be suppressed any more than the old error could. **Your choices are to write valid pre-17 code or to enable C++17 features.**

Comment: I corrected the gcc version on my question. Its gcc (GCC) 7.3.0

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this so well.